# Default enum value for optional key

Tags: swift, codable

I have a JSON object that always has `text`, and sometime has a `format` key and when it doesn't, I want to use the `.regular` case for my `SubStep.Format` enum.

I know I need to override the `init` in `SubStep` but how do I do it such that I can detect the format key, if it's nil, use `.regular`, and then just decode the `text` key that's always there?

Thanks

```
struct SubStep: Decodable {
    enum Format: String, Decodable {
        case bold = "bold"
        case regular = "regular"

        init(from decoder: Decoder) {
            do {
                let label = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self)
                self = Format(rawValue: label) ?? .regular
            } catch {
                self = .regular
            }
        }
    }

    let format: SubStep.Format
    let text: String

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       // something in here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a custom `init(from:)` method for `Format`, you only need one for `SubStep`. You need to use `container.decodeIfPresent(_:forKey:)` to decode a key which might not be present in your JSON, in which case it returns `nil`.

```
struct SubStep: Decodable {
    enum Format: String, Decodable {
        case bold
        case regular
    }

    let format: SubStep.Format
    let text: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case text, format
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.text = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .text)
        self.format = try container.decodeIfPresent(Format.self, forKey: .format) ?? .regular
    }
}
```

Unrelated to your issue, but you don't need to provide a `String` `rawValue` for your `enum` cases if their rawValue would exactly match the name of the case, the compiler will autosynthetise those for you.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, you don't have to insert the default value during parsing - you can use a computed property instead.

```
struct SubStep: Decodable {
    enum Format: String, Decodable {
        case bold
        case regular
    }

    private let formatOptional: Format?
    let text: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case formatOptional = "format"
        case text
    }

    var format: Format {
        return formatOptional ?? .regular
    }
}
```